# Scrolling a UITextview with UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

So I've created an UITextView and put it inside an UIScrollView. However, I disabled scrolling for UITextView, so I was wondering is it possible for me to scroll the textview at the same time while I'm scrolling through my UIScrollView?

I'm not sure if someone has already asked something like this, I tried to search through the site and couldn't find any topics related to my problem. If there's an existing post like this I would appreciate it if someone plink me to it.

Comment: so you wanna bind the scroll of the `UIScrollView` to the `UITextView`?

Answer (score 1):

`UIScrollView` is a scrolling `UIView`. So you need just to add the `UITextView` to the scroll view as a subview and it will scroll with it, basically something like this:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];//adjust the frame to fit your needs
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 600);//make sure the size in contentSize is bigger than the size of the scrollView frame: (400, 600) is bigger than (320, 460), otherwise the scroll effect won't be performed
UITextView *textView = [UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,400)];//adjust the frame to fit your needs
[scrollView addSubview:textView];//need to add the text view as a subview 
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: Also need to set contentSize of the scroll view.  And if the contentSize is smaller then the size of scroll view than no scrolling will occur.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you elaborate a little on the contentSize? Sorry I'm new to objective C